# Duplicate Inter_Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, workbench

[image]

```
Year    team                    name    lastname goals  teamate      goals   
1875    Philadelphia Athletics  George  Hall     12     Bill    Craver  11 
1875    Philadelphia Athletics  Bill    Craver   11     George  Hall    12
```

I'm getting output like this which is redundant.
I only want one player name and one teammate's name

Comment: you need to give more details like table structures, query etc.

Comment: Those highlighted columns gives redundant information. I need to remove that.

Comment: please paste actual code and results as text, not a screenshot, which is hard to read and impossible to copy from in order to produce an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need one team name or player name, then use a "group by" clause on those columns, and pick the aggregated values of the other columns.
For more details, you may copy and paste your query here and that will help us understand the problem more precisely.